# Windows 7: How to change taskbar font color?

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 (non-Aero) uses a very low contrast white font color on my light blue taskbar. Personalize > Window Color does not offer an option to change the taskbar font.

For Aero Themes the solution seems to be http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/24620-change-taskbars-font-color.html as two posters have been pointing out. However this does not solve my problem.

Is there any way to change this font in a non-Aero (i.e. Basic) UI Theme?

Regards,
tamberg

Answer (score 2):

You would need to take ownership of C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\Aero\aero.msstyles and then edit the font colour using something like **[Resource Hacker](http://download.cnet.com/Resource-Hacker/3000-2352_4-10178587.html)**.

Take a look at the link for details: http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/24620-change-taskbars-font-color.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Microsoft applications have become having annoying appearance, all fading, white, no contrast, and pain to the eyes.  This not only exists with Windows 7 but also with Office 2013.

Windows XP has the best appearance and is the most user-friendly.  The colors are beautiful, helpful, and everything is systematic.  There are two solutions, either return to Windows XP, or in Windows 7, open the Control Panel, choose Personalization, and then from the list of themes choose Windows Classic.  (This option gives a good contrast, although it's not as beautiful as the layout of XP, and I chose it.)

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Window Colour` section of the `Personalize` control panel then click on the `Advanced Appearance Settings` link/button and you should see the old Windows XP style dialog which lets you customise the individual elements of the desktop.

Comment: Thanks. The link seems to only be visible with Aero. And while the menu coming up is the same as the one described above it does not let you change the *taskbar* *font* *color*.

Comment: @tamberg - ah, I was looking at it in an Aero theme... apologies for the wrong info!

Answer (score 0):

Preposterous that Microsoft did not and still does not allow changing taskbar's text color, after much searching I have found a sane solution.

[image: change windows 7 taskbar color]

[Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net) has an option to tweak the color of text directly, in addition to having tons of other options to customize the Start Menu, for example turning 'All Programs' into expandable tree menu like in Windows XP, Windows 7 and 10 - donate to the author people :).