# How to change Windows 7 Aero Desktop Icon Text Color

Tags: windows, colors, icons, aero

The default icons are white on blue.  Since I am older with vision issues I find a pale green or yellow with black text easiest to read and see.  We were developed on a yellow-green planet!

I would like to try the Aero themes but cannot read the text when I change the background color to my preferred pale green.  Is there a command that I haven't found on how to change the default color for text in Aero themes (black would be nice!!

Dave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7: How to change taskbar font color?](http://superuser.com/questions/143234/windows-7-how-to-change-taskbar-font-color)

Comment: More like http://superuser.com/questions/431428/how-can-i-make-the-icon-font-color-on-a-windows-7-prof-desktop-work?rq=1

Comment: The following registry keys control color: _HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors_ & _HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors_