# How can I make the icon font color on a windows 7 prof desktop work?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, colors, desktop-icons

I have `C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Scenes\img25.jpg` as wallpaper (I think it's a standard windows wallpaper.) The desktop icon font color is white. It cannot be read without heavy eye pain. I want it to be black.

---

I couldn't change the icon font color in advanced properties (ie the good old window color settings dialog) for aero for windows 7 professional x32. I've heard that the icon font color should change automatically to suit my needs, it doesn't work as advertised in my scenario.

How could I fix it and rescue my eyes from popping out?

**EDIT** screenshot attached. sorry for bad english.

[image: desktop icon font color is wrong]

Comment: you can try this [third party tool](http://www.sillysot.com/) I think this is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an customize your desktop icon using [Iconoid](http://www.sillysot.com/) tool. Its freeware and easy to configure  now you can do whatever you want with your desktop icon.

Answer (score 1):

Since the icon font is dynamic you have to find a work around.

Go into Control Panel. At the top there is an arrow by "Control Panel" click that and find Performance Information and Tools. Click it.

You should now be at a page where the machine gives you a base score. On the left hand panel click adjust visual effects. Now comes the fun part, click 'adjust for best appearance' and play with the boxes until your desired effect.

Comment: Could you pinpoint which box gave you the effect of setting the font color? For me the text is still white and I couldn't manage to set the color this way.